# ping preload is not permitted, what could be the reason?

Tags: networking, ping

I am trying to ping one of my local host and checking CPU process to see how "Ping of death" attack behaves. I tried to ping my other PC which is in local network with `192.168.44.2` IP Address. I tried this,

```
ping -l 5000 192.168.44.2
```

and I got error like this,

```
ping: -l flag: Operation not permitted
```

I am on MacOSX Lion. How can I remove this flag so machine can let me ping with preload?

Thanks for any direction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a bit out of touch with Lion but do you not need to use `sudo` for some of the more advanced ping options?

I've been using Ubuntu of late and I know I must use `sudo` to use the -i option to set a delay between pings of less than 0.2 seconds.

Comment: Exactly I needed sudo su, and than get more permission for power :) thanks

Comment: I can confirm this.  I just tried it on my Lion box and it worked with `sudo` and gave the same "Permission denied" error without.

Comment: `sudo su`, can you just `sudo`? Or where you being general there? :)